# Datetime python3 как вывести только время?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone

Допустим у меня есть функция

```py
def get_current_time() -> datetime:
    delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=3, minutes=0)
    return datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc) + delta
```

как мне вывести только время, точнее часы и минуты? Без даты, секунд и тд

Comment: Вывести куда? На консоль?

Comment: @Streletz ну например через print

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ну например через print

Для этого Вам нужно использовать форматированный вывод. Например:

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.today()
print(date.strftime('%H:%M'))
```

Более подробно можно почитать [здесь](https://fixmypc.ru/post/rabota-s-datoi-i-vremenem-v-module-python-datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так

```
import time
time = time.asctime()
print(time[11:-8])
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну можно через костыль str. Преобразовать в строку и вывечти первый 5 символов. Но это такое.. Думаю тут получше предложат

```
print(str((datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc) + delta).time())[:5])
```

Answer (score 1):

strftime() and strptime() Format Codes

The following is a list of all the format codes that the 1989 C standard requires, and these work on all platforms with a standard C implementation.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes